# Exporting n different dataframes into separate sheets of one xlsx file

Tags: python, pandas, excel, for-loop

I have a for loop that processes multiple different dataframes that I am trying to export into one .xlsx file but in separate sheets. The dataframes are listed as dfs[i] and a corresponding sheet name as sn[i]. `save_file` is obtained from tkinter `asksaveasfilename`.

In the following loop I am trying to export the dataframes to Excel sheet tabs but I am only getting a single tab with the final dataframe in the list:

```
for i in range(len(dfs)):

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(save_file.get(), engine = 'xlsxwriter')
    dfs[i].to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sn[i], index=False)
    writer.close()
```

Similarly, I have tried this command with the same result:

```
for i in range(len(dfs)):
     with pd.ExcelWriter(save_file.get()) as writer:
          dfs[i].to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sn[i], index=False)
```

When I have tested out `print(dfs[i])` and `print(sn[i])` in that for loop it has been displaying exactly as intended, but am confused as to why only the last element in the list is getting exported to Excel. Any assistance would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 for i in range(len(dfs)):
    if not os.path.exists(save_file.get()):
        with pd.ExcelWriter(save_file.get(), engine="openpyxl", mode="w") as writer:
            dfs[i].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sn[i])
    with pd.ExcelWriter(save_file.get(), engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer:
        dfs[i].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sn[i])
```

You'll need `pip install openpyxl` first.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me! The only thing that needed to be changed was ExcelWriter as pd.ExcelWriter.

Comment: You are welcome! You could import it as (from pandas import ExcelWriter) and use it without pd. Both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_name) as writer:
       for i in range(len(dfs)):
              dfs[i].to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sn[i], index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are opening and closing the output file within the loop. Move those actions outside the loop and you should get the expected result:

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create some Pandas dataframes from some data.
dfs = [
    pd.DataFrame({"Data": [11, 12, 13, 14]}),
    pd.DataFrame({"Data": [21, 22, 23, 24]}),
    pd.DataFrame({"Data": [31, 32, 33, 34]}),
]

sn = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"]


# Write the dataframes to individual worksheets.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_multiple.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")

for i in range(len(dfs)):
    dfs[i].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sn[i], index=False)

writer.close()
```

Output:

[image]